# Node.js script running, but it won't stop!

Tags: node.js, centos

I have this test.js running in Node.js under CentOS 5. It works perfectly. Problem is, it won't stop! Even after closing my ssh client, it won't stop.

**How can I stop a running script?**

Comment: `killall name_of_script`

Comment: As stated in the answer, the problem was `screen`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Doesn't

```
$ pkill node
```

work for you?

Comment: Problem was screen. Let's the script run.

Answer (score 12):

What is the code your running, if it's the Sample code provided by nodejs.net's front-page then when your in your terminal and your server is running, you can just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to stop the current task

If you are over SSH And you wish to issue a command to stop the node processes then do something like so:

```
$ ps aux | grep node
USR  PID  1.5  0.2  44172  8260 pts/2    S    15:25   0:00 node app.js
$ kill -2 PID
```

That's just finding the PID's of the Node Processes and then killing them

Comment: It's a mini server outputting some html. But I started it via my ssh client.